# Can internal energy and entropy move in opposite directions?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, entropy

Is it possible for there to exist system for which there is some **quasistatic** process which causes this system to have $\Delta U < 0$ while $\Delta S > 0$? No constraints on the type of system as long as things are kept within the framework of equilibrium thermodynamics.

Comment: You may be looking for [negative temperature](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_temperature)

Comment: @gs But I am not specifying that other extensive parameters are constant. $dU = TdS + Y_idX_i$, so I could imagine a priori $dS >0$ (with $T>0$ as usual) while these other $dX_i <0$ to overall achieve $dU <0$.

Comment: your own comment above has just answered your question with a yes, and it is indeed yes.

Comment: This is very concerning for me. It suggests that the maximum work done in a reversible process can be unbounded (Callen equation (4.9)) would in this case read $dW_{RWS} = \frac{T_{RHS}}{T}dQ - dU$ which can be as large as we want since $\dbar Q >0$ and $-dU$ is some number. This is what initially prompted the question, as I supposed that we would have ahd the $dS <0$ requirement to obviate this possibility. @hyportnex

Comment: if  the entropy (heat) source supplies $dS^0$ at temperature $T^0$ reversibly and the work $\delta W= \sum_k Y_kdX_k$ is also done reversibly then $dU=T^0dS^0 - \delta W$. So for fixed $dU$ and $T^0$, the higher $dS^0$ the larger $\delta W$ is. I do not understand why you have a problem with this. You may be thinking of an isothermal and reversible expansion of a gas in a cylinder that must obviously end somehow, but that is just because in the $pV=RT$ model we have no limit in $V$, but that is a modeling error not of principle.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for there to exist system for which there is some
> process which causes this system to have $\Delta U < 0$ while $\Delta
> S > 0$?

Yes. An irreversible adiabatic expansion. From the first law, where $Q=0$,

$$\Delta U=-W$$

Since expansion work $W$ is positive $\Delta U\lt 0$. Also, since the expansion work is irreversible, it generates entropy, and therefore $\Delta S\gt0$.

To calculate the entropy generated, replace the irreversible adiabatic expansion with any convenient reversible path connecting the same two equilibrium states as the irreversible process and apply the following integral over the entire reversible path.

$$\Delta S=\int\frac{\delta Q_{rev}}{T}$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: I should have edited my problem to reflect that I was hoping for quasistatic processes only. I've done that now but apologize for not doing so earlier.

Comment: @EE18 Do you mean a reversible quasistatic process? Because a quasistatic process that involves friction is not a reversible process.

Comment: I just mean quasistatic. But I am not talking about entropy-generating anywhere in a composite system -- I mean within the very same system as loses internal energy.

Comment: @EE18 You're not making sense. If it's not a reversible quasistatic process then it WILL generate entropy.

Comment: I am asking about a quasistatic process wherein one subsystem obeys $\Delta S > 0$ and $\Delta U< 0$. I apologize if I'm not being clear but as far as I know that seems like a reasonable question to ask?

Comment: @EE18 You need to tell us if the process is reversible. Yes or no.

Comment: The definition of reversible I have is that a reversible process is one which is quasistatic and for which $\Delta S = 0$. Thus my specification of $\Delta S > 0$ means no, not reversible, in this case.

Comment: @EE18 In your definition is $\Delta  S=0$ the change in entropy of the system or of the system plus the surroundings?

Comment: In my definition, speaking of reversible processes only makes sense with respect to isolated systems. That is, $\Delta S = 0$ applies to "system + surroundings".

Comment: If it's an isolated system then there can be no change in entropy of the surroundings. I'm going to exit from this discussion since I really can't figure out what you are saying.

Comment: OK, my apologies. I just want to clarify for the last time (and for any future question-responders) that at no point in my OP did I say anything about a reversible process.

Comment: @EE18 you are completely missing the very important point that BobD is correctly trying to point out to you. Either you use reversible, or you use irreversible, do not use quasistatic when it can be confused. A process can have $\Delta S>0$ and still be reversible, as long as the reservoir loses the same amount of entropy. If you say that there is no entropy generation anywhere in a composite system, then quasistatic = reversible. You have been most confusing in this entire chain.

Comment: Yes, @naturallyInconsistent, I agree that a process can be reversible while having a subsystem (of the overall isolated system with respect to which the process is reversible) gain entropy, $\Delta S_{sub}>0$. But in my OP I was allowing for reversible or irreversible processes, as long as the process was quasistatic with respect to the particular subsystem, so that  $\Delta S_{sub}>0$ and $\Delta U_{sub}<0$. An irreversible adiabatic expansion as in the original answer is not quasistatic, which is what I was responding to originally.

Comment: @EE18 Regarding your last comment, my new answer uses a quasistatic adiabatic expansion, but it includes friction, which makes the quasistatic process irreversible.  All reversible processes are quasistatic, but not all quasistatic processes are reversible.

Comment: I got it, thank you again @BobD

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for there to exist system for which there is some quasistatic
> process which causes this system to have $\Delta U < 0$ while $\Delta
> S > 0$?

Yes. A quasistatic adiabatic expansion involving mechanical friction (e.g, friction between piston and cylinder). From the first law, where $Q=0$,

$$\Delta U=-W$$

Since expansion work $W$ is positive $\Delta U\lt 0$. Also, since the expansion work involves friction it is irreversible and generates entropy, and therefore $\Delta S\gt0$.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is very clear in the course of this question, and all the comments, that you have gotten yourself tangled up in confusion.

I will only consider reversible processes, and all reversible processes are quasistatic, so I am definitely in a strict subset of the processes you are allowing me to consider.

Simply consider a process that isentropically expands a lot, and isothermally absorbs only a little bit of heat. The temperature of the heat reservoir needed for the isothermal step will be different if you choose to do it first or later, and you may need infinitely many of them at different temperatures if you so choose to take a path that is neither isentropic nor isothermal. You can draw any reversible path that is closely resembled by a succession of isentropic and isothermal paths; anything not too wild will do.

Then it should be clear that $\Delta U=Q+W$ will be dominated by the negative work and thus $\Delta U<0$, but the absorption of the little bit of heat leads to $\Delta S>0$, and the criterion you are seeking is thus satisfied.

(You should not miss my comment under BobD's post's long comment thread. You really misunderstood him.)